# facebook OAth on firebase web project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, facebook-oauth

I am trying to embed Facebook oath as one of the signin methods to my web application that is using Google's firebase as a backend service.

At the moment, my app is not deployed - so I am still using localhost URL. My problem is redirecting from login to the dashboard of my app. The firefox console shows this log when I try to log in using facebook oath.

```
code: "auth/popup-closed-by-user"
message: "The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation."
stack: ""
```

On the  front-end : snippet for  .js

```
//login with facebook
const facebookButton = document.querySelector('#facebookLogin');
facebookButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
    loginForm.reset();

    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Successful Facebook Sign in");


    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Login failed");
    })


})
```

Snippet for .html file - it's just a button

```
<button id="facebookLogin">Login with Facebook</button>
```

​Has anyone experienced something like this? How did you work around it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redirecting to a new page on the front has nothing to do with the backend ... Share your code you use to redirect so we can tell whats wrong ... From the question right now we cannot tell anything

Comment: @DanyMinassian : Code shared - does it suffice? can you tell me anything now?  Thanks!

Comment: can you try running without these two lines :
 M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
 loginForm.reset();

Comment: @DanyMinassian: still the same with  "Login Failed"  -  console logged from the .js file.

Comment: Can you check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: @bojeil:  yes, the brower console has these errors : `code: "auth/popup-closed-by-user"
message: "The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation."
stack: ""`

Comment: Are there any failing network requests (non-200 responses)?